# How to export class containing `std::map` property with `std::unique_ptr` values

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I have a lib with a `Cat` class that has a property std::map `info`:

```
#ifdef LIB_EXPORT
#define LIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// Works!
class Dog {
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> info;
};

// Compile errors
class LIB_API Cat {
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> info;
};
```

Assume: The clients always use the same version of std::unique_ptr, and the memory layout of a `Cat` instance is the same as the DLL might expect.

The `Dog` class was sucessfully compiled, however the `Cat` class failed with 3 errors:

> C2280 'std::pair::pair(const std::pair &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

What should I do in order to export the `Cat` class?

Comment: Thx, let me know if the answer is concise enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Visual Studio needs to export a class, it instantiates everything possible. It will also try to create a copy constructor and copy assignment operator if they are not explicitly deleted.

Unfortunately, the member variable `info` cannot be copied because of the unique pointer. So when it tries to export the class, it fails.

Add:

```
Cat(const Cat&) = delete;
Cat& operator=(const Cat&) = delete;
```

To your class definition.

Comment: Sounds more concise than the duplicate I've selected initially, yes. Reasonings are the same tho.

Comment: Indeed, they probably are similar. Thx for checking my answer.

Comment: NP, I'm on your service here :)